# Asp.Net MVC parent Html.ViewBag from inside a partial

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am having problems to solve this on a generic way.

We have our own BeginForm and FieldFor, the beginForm calculates the PermissionLevel for that particular target url and saves some information on the ViewData. Then FieldFor uses that information to show various annotations on the rendered controls.

Now the problem is when a partial is used to render the fields inside the form. It seems that the parent's ViewData is not available inside the partial (wich is rendered using the default Html.Partial extension) so the annotations are not shown.

Debugging it i found that the ViewData property of the WebViewPage is shared, but the one on Html.ViewData is not. Since i am using a helper to render the fields i only have the viewdata inside the HtmlHelper and not the property of the view.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no Html.ViewBag, ViewBag is a property from ControllerBase class. Even in a partial view you should access @ViewBag.YourProperty, can you show us some code ?

Comment: Please post your code that renders the partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you just use the following

```
@ViewBag.Property
```

You didn't specify how you are rendering your partial, but in some cases you may need to use the following to get to the viewbag if the method you are using to render the partial is not carrying the ViewBag across.

```
@ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.Property
```

Comment: Html.ViewContext.Controller.ViewData worked thanks! I am using Partial to render the view so it is using the same controller.. I need some sleep :P